# Ways to do One-to-many relations in android room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm looking for a way to create a one-to-many relationship using room. I've seen several examples with two approaches. I don't fully understand them. I didn't write full DAO yet, so maybe I'm missing something there.

**Approach 1 with @Embedded**

As in [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#one-to-many) documentation, the relation is done via *@Embedded* tag. In this scenario is not needed to set a *ForeignKey*? How to do a *ondelete cascade* if needed?

```
@Entity
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey val userId: Long,
    val name: String,
    val age: Int
)

@Entity
data class Playlist(
    @PrimaryKey val playlistId: Long,
    val userCreatorId: Long,
    val playlistName: String
)

data class UserWithPlaylists(
    @Embedded val user: User,
    @Relation(
          parentColumn = "userId",
          entityColumn = "userCreatorId"
    )
    val playlists: List<Playlist>
)
```

Does the *UserWithPlaylists* needs the *@Entity* tag?

**Approach 2 with @ForeignKey**

```
@Entity
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey val userId: Long,
    val name: String,
    val age: Int
)

@Entity(foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(entity = SeriesGroup::class,
    parentColumns = arrayOf("playlistId"),
    childColumns = arrayOf("userCreatorId")])
data class Playlist(
    @PrimaryKey val playlistId: Long,
    val userCreatorId: Long,
    val playlistName: String
)
```

In this scenario is not needed to create a new Class joining both Entities? Also, I don't understand why *ForeignKey*, *parentColumns* and *childColumns* must be of type *array*. Shouldn't in this case be *parentColumns* an array and *childColumns* a Long (as we have one  - to many relation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As in this documentation, the relation is done via @Embedded tag. In
> this scenario is not needed to set a ForeignKey? How to do a ondelete
> cascade if needed?

This approach is for retrieving data, to make Room generate queries for you. To do onDelete Cascade etc  you need a ForeignKey.

> Does the UserWithPlaylists needs the @Entity tag?

No

> In this scenario is not needed to create a new Class joining both
> Entities? Also, I don't understand why ForeignKey, parentColumns and
> childColumns must be of type array. Shouldn't in this case be
> parentColumns an array and childColumns a Long (as we have one - to
> many relation)?

You need some class for every query result, so if you want to query something from both tables, you will need to create one. There is also many-to-many relations support, so you might need multiple keys.

Both approaches are usually used, they do not exclude, but complement each other.